# token-pattern for numbers in tfidfvectorizer sklearn in python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tokenize, tfidfvectorizer

I need to calculate the tfidf matrix for few sentences. sentence include both numbers and words.
I am using below code to do so

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

data1=['1/8 wire','4 tube','1-1/4 brush']
dataset=pd.DataFrame(data1, columns=['des'])
vectorizer1 = TfidfVectorizer(lowercase=False)
tf_idf_matrix = pd.DataFrame(vectorizer1.fit_transform(dataset['des']).toarray(),columns=vectorizer1.get_feature_names())
```

Tfidf function is considering only words as its vocabulary i.e

```
Out[3]: ['brush', 'tube', 'wire']
```

but i need numbers to be part of tokens

expected

```
Out[3]: ['brush', 'tube', 'wire','1/8','4','1-1/4']
```

After reading [TfidfVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html) documentation, I came to know have to change **token_pattern** and **tokenizer** parameters. But I am not getting how to change it to consider numbers and punctuation.

can anyone please tell me how to change the parameters.

Comment: @coldspeed. perfect answer.Thank you so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, `token_pattern` requires a custom regex pattern, pass a regex that treats any one or more characters that don't contain whitespace characters as a single token.

```
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(lowercase=False, token_pattern=r'\S+') 
tf_idf_matrix = pd.DataFrame(
    tfidf.fit_transform(dataset['des']).toarray(), 
    columns=tfidf.get_feature_names()
)
```

```
print(tf_idf_matrix)

      1-1/4       1/8         4     brush      tube      wire
0  0.000000  0.707107  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.707107
1  0.000000  0.000000  0.707107  0.000000  0.707107  0.000000
2  0.707107  0.000000  0.000000  0.707107  0.000000  0.000000
```

Answer (score 1):

you can explicitly point out in token_pattern parameter the symbols you would like to parse:

```
    token_pattern_ = r'([a-zA-Z0-9-/]{1,})'
```

where {1,} indicates the minimum number of symbols the word should contain. End then you pass this as a parameter to token_pattern:

```
    tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(token_pattern = token_pattern_)
```